# All arrays must be of the same length

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, machine-learning

I am getting an error like this. Thank you in advance for your solutions.

ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

```
import numpy as np   
import pandas as pd  

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'name':['work_type', np.nan],
                      'work_type':['Private', 'Self-employed', 'Govt_job', np.nan]})
```

Comment: There is no solution, the error message literally tells you what the problem is. You can't have a matrix-like structure if your columns don't have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each column value to be a list then you need to use double squared brackets

```
import numpy as np   
import pandas as pd  

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'name':[['work_type', np.nan]],
                      'work_type':[['Private', 'Self-employed', 'Govt_job', np.nan]]})
```